# DolphinDB: filter conditions and order of execution

Tags: group-by, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group, percentile

Here is a table `tb` of two stocks.

```html
trade_date secu_code value
---------- --------- -----
2017.01.11 600570    1    
2017.01.11 600000    2    
2017.01.11 600570    3    
2017.01.11 600000    4    
2017.01.11 600570    5    
2017.01.11 600000    6    
2017.01.11 600570    7    
2017.01.11 600000    8    
2017.01.11 600570    9    
2017.01.11 600000    10   
2017.01.12 600570    11   
2017.01.12 600000    12   
2017.01.12 600570    13   
2017.01.12 600000    14   
2017.01.12 600570    15   
2017.01.12 600000    16   
2017.01.12 600570    17   
2017.01.12 600000    18   
2017.01.12 600570    19   
2017.01.12 600000    20
```

I want to calculate the average daily value for each stock. First the data is grouped by security code and trade date, then filtered by the where condition (values that are no greater than 40th percentile).

```html
select secu_code,trade_date, avg(value) as factor_value from tb where value <= percentile(value,40)
group by trade_date,secu_code order by trade_date,secu_code
```

The output is as follows:

```html
secu_code trade_date factor_value
--------- ---------- ------------
600000    2017.01.11 5           
600570    2017.01.11 4
```

However, if I take the record of the stock 600000 in 2017.01.11, and calculate its average daily value, I will get the following result.

```html
select secu_code,trade_date, avg(value) as factor_value from tb where trade_date=2017.01.11 and secu_code =`600000 and value <= percentile(value,40) group by trade_date,secu_code order by trade_date,secu_code
```

```html
secu_code trade_date factor_value
--------- ---------- ------------
600000    2017.01.11 3
```

The results I obtain with the above two methods are different. How come? Which one is the correct?

Answer (score 0):

There is certain order of execution when using SQL statements. First, the where clause extracts the records that satisfy the specified conditions, and then the remaining rows are grouped and calculated.

You can refer to [SQL statements: Order of Execution](https://www.dolphindb.com/help200/SQLStatements/orderOfExecute.html) for more details.

The user-defined aggregate functions or higher-order function `aggrTopN` may help you out.

Simulated data:

```
trade_date=sort(take(2017.01.11..2017.01.12,20))
secu_code=take(`600570`600000,20)
value=1..20
tb=table(trade_date,secu_code,value)
```

Solution 1:

Use the user-defined aggregate function.

```
defg percentile_40(x){
 ret = NULL
 y = percentile(x,40)
 z = iif( x<y,x,0)
 cc = sum(x<y) 
 if (cc > 0)
 {ret = sum(z)\cc}
 return ret
 }

select secu_code,trade_date, percentile_40(value) as factor_value from tb_1 group by trade_date,secu_code order by trade_date,secu_code
```

Output:

```
secu_code trade_date factor_value
--------- ---------- ------------
600000    2017.01.11 3           
600570    2017.01.11 2           
600000    2017.01.12 13          
600570    2017.01.12 12
```

Solution 2:

Use the higher-order function `aggrTopN`.

```
select aggrTopN(avg, funcArgs=value, sortingCol=value, top=0.4, ascending=true) as factor_value from tb group by trade_date,secu_code
```